# convert GBX in GBP values with GOOGLEFINANCE

Tags: google-apps-script, stock

I´m trying to calculate the value of the stocks depending of the different currencies. I tested including IF condition but it is not working:

[EDITED] Thinking better, It can be more dynamic if I calculate the historical prices that we obtain from GOOGLEFINANCE and divided by /100. This function insert in A1, the GOOGLEFINANCE formula to get the historical price, but I´m not sure how to include the operation to divide by 100 the values that I obtain:

```
function generateHistoricalPriceSheetForSymbol(symbol, fromDate) {
  var symbolSheet = createNewOrClearOldSheet(symbol)

  var fromDateFunction = "DATE(" + fromDate.getFullYear() + "," + (fromDate.getMonth() + 1) + "," + fromDate.getDate() + ")"
  var historicalPricesFormula = 'GOOGLEFINANCE("' + symbol + '", "price", ' + fromDateFunction + ', TODAY(), "DAILY")'
  symbolSheet.getRange('A1').setFormula(historicalPricesFormula)

  var fontFamily = getConfigurationByKey('Font Family')
  var dateFormat = getConfigurationByKey('Date Format')
  symbolSheet.getRange('A:A').setNumberFormat(dateFormat).setFontFamily(fontFamily)
  var numberFormat = getConfigurationByKey('Number Format')
  symbolSheet.getRange('B:B').setNumberFormat(numberFormat).setFontFamily(fontFamily)

  cleanUnusedCells(symbolSheet)
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible.  Please tell us the error and give us the code to reproduce it.

Comment: Logical comparision for equal is `==`.  Try changing `symbol="LON:DGE"` to `symbol == "LON:DGE"`

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what the desired output is? Do you want to divide the values returned by `GOOGLEFINANCE` by 100? What's the reason for this?

Comment: Yes, i want that the values returned will be /100 because googlefinance takes GBX instead of GBP, so it is multiply by 100.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

You want to divide the values returned by `GOOGLEFINANCE` by 100.

#### Solution:

In order to modify the values returned by `GOOGLEFINANCE`, you could use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) on these. You'd just have to use [arithmetic operators](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#arithmetic-operators) to divide column 2 by 100.

Just replace this:

```
var historicalPricesFormula = 'GOOGLEFINANCE("' + symbol + '", "price", ' + fromDateFunction + ', TODAY(), "DAILY")';
```

With this:

```
var historicalPricesFormula = 'QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("' + symbol + '", "price", ' + fromDateFunction + ', TODAY(), "DAILY"), "SELECT Col1, Col2/100 LABEL Col1 \'Date\', Col2/100 \'Close\'")';
```

Comparison:

[image]